# Incorrect integer value: 'time()' for column 'created_on'

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to retrieve current time and date in codeigniter in timestamp format. Here are the few lines of code.

```
 $data = array(
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
        'email' => $email,
        'ip_address' => $ip_address,
        'created_on' => time(),
        'date_created' => time(),
        'active' => '1',
        'user_type_id' => '2'
    );
```

Here, in created_on column i would like to have the value of current date and time in timestamp format. 
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html

Comment: And what is the problem with `time()`?

Comment: Incorrect integer value: 'time()' for column 'created_on' @u_mulder

Comment: What is the type of `created_on` column? And why is `time()` in quotes?

Comment: Again, what type of column is the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

`$this->db->set('created_on', time(), false);`

for the fields with timestamps and leave them out of the data array.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
date("Y-m-d"); // this will show the data in the format year-month-day
date("H:i:s"); // this will show the data in the format 14:36:55
```

```
$data = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'email' => $email,
    'ip_address' => $ip_address,
    'created_on' => date("H:i:s"),
    'date_created' => date("Y-m-d"),
    'active' => '1',
    'user_type_id' => '2'
);
```

Comment: Did you read a question? `in timestamp format`

Comment: Timestamp format?

Comment: @u_mulder I would like to save the value in timestamp format